# Would any configuration or INNODB principle cause the following MYSQL update to not necessarilly perform all updates?

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

```
<?php
    $query = 'SELECT id FROM transaction_table';
    $result = db_query($query);  
    while($row = db_fetch_array($result)) {    
        //do some processing
        db_query('UPDATE transaction_table SET updated = "1" WHERE id = "%s"',$row['id']);
    }
?>
```

Every time this script run, it only updates a few random rows (8-25 on average). It should be updating all the rows.

Comment: There is probably more to this problem or else you could just run `UPDATE transaction_table SET updated = "1"` which will update all records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

echo out the query on each loop.  My guess is that there are a few that error out.  Use this code:

```
<?php
    $query = 'SELECT id FROM transaction_table';
    $result = db_query($query);  
    while($row = db_fetch_array($result)) {    
        //do some processing
        echo 'UPDATE transaction_table SET updated = "1" WHERE id = "'.$row['id'].'"<br>';
        db_query('UPDATE transaction_table SET updated = "1" WHERE id = "%s"',$row['id']);
    }
?>
```

Try running each query manually in MySQL directly and verify each will run.  I can't see anything in the code you gave us that would cause any issues.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason that I can think of is that this will fail to update rows that are inserted after the `SELECT`.

I hope that I am misreading this, but the [Drupal `db_fetch_array` reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/db_fetch_array/6) describes this function as:

> Fetch one result row from the previous query as an array.

This doesn't really mean **the previous query** does it?  I would hope that you can have more than one query active at a time.  Note that I have never used Drupal so I'm not sure how literal the documentation is.  If the documentation can be read literally, then I would be worried that the `db_query('UPDATE...')` is going to cause the next `db_fetch_array` call to go awry somehow.